# No decimal places.. everything else is fine

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to limit the decimal of the average to 2.. here is the code:

```
select P.prodid, P.prodname, Q.score as "Average Score"
from qualitycheck Q
inner join  product P
on P.prodid = Q.prodid
where Q.score >= (select ROUND( AVG(score),2) from qualitycheck where score >= 2.0)
group by  P.prodid, P.prodname, Q.score
order by 3 ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle, you can use [TO_CHAR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) to format with 2 decimals;

```
select P.prodid, P.prodname, TO_CHAR(Q.score, '9999999999.99') as "Average Score"
from qualitycheck Q
...rest of query
```

Note that you need enough digits in your format string to cover the max number of integer digits you want displayed, otherwise Oracle will format the number as `#####`.

EDIT: Old answer on MySQL; You'll need to use [`FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) to get a fixed number of decimal places;

```
select P.prodid, P.prodname, FORMAT(Q.score, 2) as "Average Score"
from qualitycheck Q
...rest of query...
```

Note that this will convert `Average Score` to a string to keep the decimals even in the case where not that many decimals are really required for the number, for example '12.00'.

Comment: select P.prodid, P.prodname, FORMAT(Q.score, 2) as "Average Score"
                             *

Error at line 1:
ORA-00904: "FORMAT": invalid identifier

Comment: @user2329362 Your question is tagged MySQL, but you're giving an Oracle error message. Which is it?

Comment: with that the decimal appears, but it s just the whole number with number of decimals eg: (3.00) not the exact average.. eg (2.94)

Comment: @ak_ny Since you're grouping by Q.score, you're getting an average exactly equal to Q.score (which presumably is an integer). You'll need to figure out what you actually want the average of, and rewrite the question somehow. That part is not related to the number formatting though.